# Checking for duplicate phone numbers, works fine until we have more than 4

Tags: java, arraylist, duplicates

Me and my friend is working with a program that should be handling customers. The thing is that we need to check if a telephone number is used on more than one customer. The code works fine until we reach 4 customers with the same number... It then prints out the last customer with that number twice! We can't figure out what is wrong with it, so would be lovely if you could throw a quick eye on our code :)

```
//CASE 10: LISTA TELEFONNUMMER SOM FLER ÄN EN KUND HAR        
public static void listaTelNr() {   
    String KtelefonNr;
    String Knamn;
        for(int y=0;y<TelefonNrLista.size();y++){
            for(int x=y+1;x<TelefonNrLista.size();x++){
                if (TelefonNrLista.get(y).getTelNr().equals(TelefonNrLista.get(x).getTelNr())){
                    KtelefonNr=TelefonNrLista.get(y).getTelNr();
                    Knamn= TelefonNrLista.get(y).getKundNamn();
                    SammaTelNr nySammaTelNr=new SammaTelNr(KtelefonNr,Knamn);
                    SammaTelNrLista.add(nySammaTelNr);
                    KtelefonNr=TelefonNrLista.get(x).getTelNr();
                    Knamn= TelefonNrLista.get(x).getKundNamn();
                    SammaTelNr nySammaTelNr2=new SammaTelNr(KtelefonNr,Knamn);
                    SammaTelNrLista.add(nySammaTelNr2);

            }
    }
        }



        for(int y=0;y<SammaTelNrLista.size();y++){
            for(int x=y+1;x<SammaTelNrLista.size();x++){
                if (SammaTelNrLista.get(y).getKundNamn().equals(SammaTelNrLista.get(x).getKundNamn())){
                    SammaTelNrLista.remove(x);

                }
            }
                }
        for(int i=0;i<SammaTelNrLista.size();i++){
        System.out.println(SammaTelNrLista.get(i));
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code instead of posting link to code?

Comment: If you can pinpoint when the error occurs, you've already done the hard bit of the job. Just run the code in a debugger and you should be able to figure out what goes wrong. You'll also learn more from the experience than from someone else telling you what the problem is.

Comment: Please don't make it hard for us to help you.  I don't speak the language that your identifier names are written in, which makes it hard to work out which of your method calls are intended to get the customer's phone number, and so on.  You are more likely to get help on Stack Overflow if you paste your code into the question, and if English speakers are able to understand what the code does.

Answer (score 2):

Store your number-customer relation in a map and your code will be much cleaner  and faster.

```
// Map<phoneNumber, customerList>    
Map<String, List<Customer>> phoneNumberCustomersMap = new ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is most likely related to the fact that you are trying to remove elements from the list SammaTelNrLista in a for loop. To safely remove from a collection you should use an Iterator.

Also, you could make you solution a bit more efficient if you remove the filtering step. When adding elements to the SammaTelNrLista list you can check if the name is already in the list. And only add it if it's not there. You could use a map for this.

Answer (score 0):

In your first loop: if the names are not equal and the numbers are equal then add the number to a HashSet. After that loop over the entries of the hash set and print them.